# Other term for transcribe

Tags: synonyms

In a technical environment what's the correct term to use if I wanted to ask people to check what's wrong with a code I "transcribed" from an old notation to the current standards?

I thought these words ('transcribed', 'updated', 'changed') were okay but they don't seem to be the right ones to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Transcribe' wouldn't be the normal usage here, which implies that you made an exact copy of the old copy, which isn't what you did if you changed standards.

You could say:

"I *re-wrote* the old version of the code with our new standards"

Or

"I *changed* the old version of the code to use our new standards"

Or

"I *updated* the old version of the code to use our new standards"

They key here, is that you want to signify that the old code wasn't only copied, but changed as well, which in the cases above are signified by changed, updated, or re-written.

Personally, I would use re-wrote or updated, which both imply that you're making the code more current, which is what you're doing by using new standards.

Answer (score 2):

The overall process is referred to as [Software Maintenance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_maintenance), but I believe that you could say that you **modified** the code - in other words, you modified the software to keep a software product usable in a changed or changing environment.

Comment: It is still usable but the code is using a notation intended for backwards compatibility purposes on legacy systems. `Modified` is a valid option but I think I'll use `re-wrote` or `re-written`.